# ArcGIS Pro performance issue when using Text in Layout?

Tags: arcgis-pro, performance, layouts, text

A few weeks ago I began to notice that certain map projects I was working on in ArcGIS Pro were running extremely slow when I tried making adjustments to the map Layout, specifically moving around text elements. The confusing thing for me is that the functions you would expect to make the system lag, like geoprocessing or editing, are running fine; it doesn't appear the content of the maps has anything to do with the problem. The issue only appears when I try to add or move around text elements in the Layout pane.

Has anyone experienced anything similar and have a fix for this?

Comment: You have tagged ArcGIS Pro 1.2, are you using Pro 1.2?

Comment: update ArcGIS Pro to 2.7 will help fix those known bugs.

Comment: @Mapperz, is 2.7 out?  I have 2.6.3 and it shows as current.

Comment: 2.7 Documentation is out https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/arcgis-pro-system-requirements.htm so the download should follow....in esri minutes/days but is very soon.